# Ubuntu 22.04 won't recognize keyboard/mouse via KVM switch

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, kvm-switch

I have been having a strange issue since upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and am struggling to troubleshoot it. My desktop keyboard and mouse are routed through a Blackbird USB 2.0 KVM switch. Plugged into the switch are the monitor (HDMI), keyboard, Logitech wireless mouse, and a hub containing a webcam and a CD drive. The KVM is shared with a Windows laptop, where everything works fine. All packages on the Ubuntu desktop is up to date.

When the KVM switches over to the Ubuntu desktop, the keyboard and mouse are not recognized and do not show up as devices under `lsusb`. The camera and CD drive, plugged into the same KVM, work fine and appear in `lsusb`. The keyboard and mouse work fine if plugged into the desktop directly.

On boot, I see the error message below that I can't quite decipher:

[image]

I've tried swapping pretty much every cable involved, the cables are not bad. I am completely unsure why Ubuntu is "unable to enumerate USB device" but is able to recognize some of the devices plugged into the KVM.
An update as I continue to try and debug this - running `dmesg` and plugging/unplugging both the mouse and the keyboard in the KVM shows absolutely no response.

Answer (score 1):

KVM switches don't work fully if Intel VT isn't enabled at the BIOS level - lesson learned!